# How to stop TTS during a income call?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

How to stop TTS during a incoming call..? Whether I need to create a separate activity?

Update:

How to use Phonelistener from a TTS activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [PhoneStateListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and then stop the TTS when the phones receives a call.

Comment: Know that? But whether I need to create a separate activity for it?